# Python module function not defined

Tags: import, module, python-3.4

I am trying to import a module in my python script and I can't make it work.
So I have my python script: /home/user/pythonscript/oneDir/onescript.py
And I would like to use a script that is a directory higher in hierarchy:
/home/user/pythonscript/common.py
So I did the following at the top of my onescript.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/home/user/pythonscript')
import common
```

In my common.py file, I have a function onecConnect, and when I try to run onescript.py, which uses onecConnect function, I get the following error: nameError: name 'onecConnect' is not defined

Anyone can see what I do wrong or forgot to do?
Thanks

Comment: What is the traceback of the error?

Comment: Are you doing `onecConnect()`, or `common.onecConnect()`?

Comment: In the console the only thing I see is Traceback (most recet call last): File "onescript.py", line 25, in <module> s = oneConnect() NameError: name 'onecConnect' is not defined

I am calling onecConnect, not common.onecConnect (I tried it and got a bunch of errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there are `__init__.py` in all directories, go to `/home/user/pythonscript` and run Python code from there. So:

```
python oneDir/onescript.py
```

In `onescript.py` you can do:

```
from common import onecConnect
```

The rules are:

- Always run a Python script from the highest possible directory (not the deepest into the project).
- Always have full import lines, no relative imports.

This keeps the problems away.

Comment: do I really have to import each function that I want to use from 'common'? I though I could just import common and then use all functions that's in it ?!

Comment: @MelodieGauthier: yes, that's possible too. That depends on your preference and how many functions you need.

Comment: _"yes, that's possible too."_. Ok, so... How do you do it?